# Allow actions on custom object by profile

Tags: community, profile, delete, global-actions, edit

I defined a new `cutstom object` in `Salesforce` named: `file_Uploaded__c` with many fields like `File_Name`, `file_Size` , ... but i don't know how to restrict actions like `delete` or `edit` based on the `User profile`: for example if the connected user has a `System administrator` profile he can edit and delete the records of my custom object, but if he has `Marketing User` profile he can only view the records of the object without deleting or editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using EE editions and up you can go to Setup-->Administer-->Manage Users-->Profiles--> select the appropriate profile that you want to make changes--> Press on the edit button on the top middle and scroll down (see the image below and check the appropriate checkbox)

[image]

Hope this will help you.

PS. Don't forget o mark this answer as the best if it's helpful.

Comment: thanks for the answer. What i found the option in `Setup-->Administer-->Manage Users-->Profiles`. Then i choose a profile and i select `Object Settings` and then i give the permissions i want